# QgsDefaultValue class in python

Tags: pyqgis

In C++ API if I am not mistaken there is class QgsDefaultValue, so we can programmatically set default values(expression) to a field.

Is there python alternative to that?

All research leads to defining trigger on create feature, but it is not really what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [`QgsDefaultValue`](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiT-vX8u8_XAhUH5KQKHUNUBasQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fqgis.org%2Fapi%2FclassQgsDefaultValue.html&usg=AOvVaw3bba7LslBZWgd8KIzyLWBM) class in QGIS [but only starting with QGIS 3](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDefaultValue.html#details). It supports an additional flag, if the default value should also be applied on update. This exists in the C++ and the Python API.

For QGIS 2.18 there is a [`QgsVectorLayer::setDefaultValueExpression(fieldIndex, expression)`](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a33f2bed3122d6df1644b9c978ea4da71) function that does the same (without on update flag). This exists in the C++ and Python API.

Comment: that was the problem. still using 2.18 :) Thanks.